# How to draw a hover effect behind a bar chart?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS in my website. I want to make an interactive bar chart where the user by clicking on a certain index of the bar will get data from it in a table.

I was trying to make the chart more user-friendly where on hover they will see a *shadow* behind the bar so they will almost understand that they have to click on it.

The issue is that the drawn shadow is too large and the bar index and looks like this:

[image]

While what I'm looking for is that gray background only on the hovered index so it should fill only the first data under MIRKO T label.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
Chart.controllers.bar = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
    draw: function (ease) {
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
        if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
            var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
                ctx = this.chart.ctx,
                x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                topY = 1000000,
                width = activePoint._view.width,
                bottomY = 0;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
            ctx.lineTo(x + width * 1.3, bottomY);
            ctx.lineWidth = width * 4.3;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.11)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by playing with the `lintTo` and `lineWidth` values

my final code looks like this:

```
Chart.controllers.bar = Chart.controllers.bar.extend({
    draw: function (ease) {
        Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
        if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
            var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
                ctx = this.chart.ctx,
                x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                topY = 1000000,
                width = activePoint._view.width,
                bottomY = 0;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
            ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
            ctx.lineWidth = width + 20;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.1)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
});
```